# JPA : What is the best way to detect entity changes

Tags: jpa, javers

I would like to have your opinion on the most appropriate and optimized way to detect changes of an entity during an update operation.

My proposal:

1. I have a Person object as a parameter (from a controler rest)
2. I load from the persistence the object in database, as well as these list (lazy) to have all the child data
3. I detach the object from the persistence context (necessary so that after saving, the loaded object is not updated)
4. I use JaVers to recover the diff

   ```
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager entityManager;

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public String update(Person updatedPerson) {
       Person personInDb = getDetached(person.getId()));

       Person updated = personRepo.save(updatedPerson);

       Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE).build();

       return javers.compare(personInDb, updated);

   }

   private Person getDetached(Long id) {
       Person person = personRepo.findById(id)
           .orElseThrow(() -> new MyException("Person not found"));

       // fetch lazy collections
       person.getAccounts().size();
       person.getProfiles().size();
       person.getAuthorization().size();

       entityManager.detach(person);

       return person;
   }
   ```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question

Comment: @BartekWalacik How can we detect the change of an entity at the update to use it as a changelog for example.
I proposed my way of doing things (using Javers to merge between the entity passed in parameter and that existing in detached database), is it valid? is there another more optimal way?
This is not really a question, but a request for opinions :-)

Comment: If you want to track changes on an entity, simply use javersRepository javers.commit() not javers.compare()